# Gerber files sequence

Tags: pcb, production, gerber, stack-up

I have the following Gerber files from the manufacturer for order confirmation. As I inspected them, I have inferred that the order of the copper layers from top to bottom are **tl**, **l3**, **l2** and **bl**. But when I check the vias **l2** seems to be the ground layer. So the result Signal(Top) **tl**-PWR **l3**-GND **l2**-Signal(Bottom) **bl** seems to be in conflict with my PCB stack-up, which is Signal(Top)-GND-PWR-Signal(Bottom). Which sequence is correct?

```
bl
bo
bs
drl
gbp
gbr
gtp
ko
l2
l3
npth
sk
tl
to
ts
vcut
```

Comment: Are the copper layers numbered with a box and layer numbers so you can hold it up to a light source and see them in sequence?

Comment: Hello winny , PCB is not produced yet. They have sent the Gerber files for conformation. I have opened them in KiCad, but have doubts about inner layer sequencing. Since Gerber file convention varies, should I ask this question to the manufacturer?

Comment: your paragraph is a wall of text please reformat your list to be easily readable.

Comment: I don't this there is enough infromation here,  are there any other files from the manufacturer?

Comment: I always include a "readme" file with a PCB order.  That file clearly lists the provided files and their intended purpose/layer order, as there is no totally Official file name convention - different CAD systems use different file names or extensions.